# How do I resolve: undefined reference to __mingw_get_msvcrt_handle?

Tags: cmake, gfortran, mingw-w64

I'm building [ECCODES](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/ECC/Releases) on a Windows system using MinGW64.  ECCODES is built with CMake, and includes Fortran and C source.  After considerable pain finding a `gfortran` [version](http://simplyfortran.com/) that would build the Fortran code in this Windows environment, I've gotten everything to compile, but a Fortran executable won't build because of one lousy undefined reference, to `__mingw_get_msvcrt_handle`.  How do I solve this?

```
c:/progra~2/simply~1/mingw-~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/
  ../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.text+0x2b8):
  undefined reference to `__mingw_get_msvcrt_handle'
```

Comment: Could be a mix-up of two toolchains (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540673/mingw-cross-compiling-error-undefined-reference-to-mingw-get-msvcrt-handle)). Please consider [`make` with verbose output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands) to see if you have a library path pointing to another toolchain installation.

Comment: Thanks @Florian. Trying it now.