# How to bundle a Gtk-rs and rusqlite program for Windows from Linux?

Tags: deployment, rust, cross-compiling, gtk-rs, rusqlite

I have a Rust program that depends on libgtk3 and sqlite3 and I would like to generate an installer/executable for x86 Windows. I do not have access to a Windows machine so I need to bundle it from my primary development platform, x86 Linux.

How does one approach cross-compilation in Rust?

Comment: This won't help with local development, but many CI services (e.g. [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/specifications-for-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources)) support Windows builds.

Comment: Hey Hossain Adnan. Does this answer your question? [Cross-compile a Rust application from Linux to Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492799/cross-compile-a-rust-application-from-linux-to-windows)

Comment: @MaxV only partially, still unsure how to create an .msi/.exe bundle that includes my version of libgtk etc for the users.