# How do I compile a cargo project for other platforms?

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo, kde-plasma, arch

I am just starting to learn rust and I want to send my friend a little program I made. However, I am on windows and he is using an Arch based OS (I think one of the Manjaro KDE ones). How would I compile my cargo project to work on his OS? Or any other platform really.

Well I don't really know where to start. I'm not exactly an experienced professional.

Comment: Search for the term "cross compilation".

Answer (score 2):

Your question is essentially the same as [Cross-compile a Rust application from Linux to Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492799/cross-compile-a-rust-application-from-linux-to-windows) you just have to replace the target triple in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62853319/442760) with `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`:

```bash
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

and distribute the file `target/debug/<your_crate_name>`

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for Windows to Linux on the same architecture, you can use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install). This is likely the easiest method.

Otherwise, you can use `rustup target add` from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75728305/442760). You likely need to find the linker for the target platform.

The most flexible method is to use [cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross).